# Is it possible from a script to identify the moment when VS 2022 is done processing all the background tasks and loading the Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, automation, envdte

I have a large solution with mixed SDK style and Legacy style projects. I need to implement some automation, but I must not start until VS is done with its background tasks and loading intellisense, like this:
[image]

I do not care the Status Bar says "Ready". As far as I am concerned it is not ready as long as these background tasks are not done and the Intellisense is not completely loaded.

I am running VS with the `MSBuildDebugEngine` environment variable set to 1. I can set any other environment variables if needed - I have full control over how the IDE is started.

Is it possible from a script to indentify this moment? I have the `DTE2` object as well.